# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: support

The question [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3296/why-was-my-comment-removed) about why one of my comments was removed, was then itself removed. Now, not only am I left with no information as to why my comment was considered unsuitable as the question was never answered, but I'm also left in the dark as to why the question was considered unsuitable.

It seems a somewhat perverse way to mould a site into the shape the community wants by simply deleting posts that do not fit without any explanation and leaving users to guess what the problem with them might be, but even if that were to be the accepted strategy, what would then be the purpose of the Meta site, on which the question was posted?

In case the link does not work (the question having been deleted) it was simply - Why was my comment removed?. The similar questions [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/mystified-at-why-a-bunch-of-my-questions-have-been-closed), [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/a-non-nietzsche-deleted-answer-how-to-fix), [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/is-it-regular-practice-to-both-close-and-remove-questions) and [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1679/why-was-my-question-on-iit-closed) all seem to have been deemed suitable fare for Meta so I'm not sure what was so different about mine.

Comment: It had become a discussion thread and wasn't adding long-term value. If you're really this concerned about a single comment, maybe consider *adding your thoughts as answers* rather than as throwaway comments! Keep in mind comments aren't for extended discussion, nor is meta. (Please consider using the chat spaces if you'd just like to talk!)

Comment: I'm not significantly concerned about a single comment, I'm concerned about learning to write questions, answers and comments which fit the requirements of this site. What I'm finding is that no-one seems to want to say what those requirements are.. All I've got so far from you is that 1. Comments are not for extended discussion - The comment that was deleted was the second one and an 8 comment discussion was attached the the other answer, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: 2. Comments are not for open-ended or speculative discussion - Firstly, neither are answers, but you suggested (twice now) that I put my comments in an answer instead, so it seems you didn't consider my comment open-ended or speculative. Also, the discussion in the answer above my comment was about whether God was sporting with us, so definitions of open-endedness and speculation are clearly quite broad here.

Comment: 3. Meta is not for open-ended discussion either - Firstly, why then is there a 'Discussion' Tag? Secondly if asking why a question was deleted is unsuitable for Meta, why are all the other questions I've linked still on meta?

Comment: I feel like I've asked a very simple question and keep getting vague generalisations and obfuscation in return. Perhaps some clarification might help. I could rephrase it as "Why were my comments and questions deleted when other equally extended, open-ended, speculative or otherwise related questions/comments were not?". What was it specifically that was wrong with them? I really don't see how that's too much to ask.

Comment: further discussion/complaints about this is not going to achieve much, but if you are legitimately confused about what comments are for on StackExchange, it may help to review some of the SE guidance around what sorts of comments are constructive; please do take a look if you are actually interested in getting help/explanations about what sorts of behavior is encouraged -- keep in mind mods can delete any comment for any reason (but there is specific guidance on why critical or editorializing comments may not be appropriate) http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: You are welcome to discuss this further in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "talking to a wall" in chat. If there is nobody in the room at the moment, you can either ping them using @, or leave a message and wait for someone to read it later.